Converting CJS Module to ECMAScript when export contain an arrow function
On Server Application Structure documentation page of Socket.io, two methods are presented to use modules for better code clarity. Those modules are CommonJS.
I managed to translate the first to ESM, but the syntax of the second one blocks me, with the (io) => containing multiple functions.
As a reference, here is the code :

index.js
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);

const { createOrder, readOrder } = require("./orderHandler")(io);
const { updatePassword } = require("./userHandler")(io);

const onConnection = (socket) => {
  socket.on("order:create", createOrder);
  socket.on("order:read", readOrder);

  socket.on("user:update-password", updatePassword);
}

io.on("connection", onConnection);



orderHandler.js
module.exports = (io) => {
  const createOrder = function (payload) {
    const socket = this; // hence the 'function' above, as an arrow function will not work
    // ...
  };

  const readOrder = function (orderId, callback) {
    // ...
  };

  return {
    createOrder,
    readOrder
  }
}

What is your solution to translate those two files and keeping the same one-line clarity as :
socket.on("user:update-password", updatePassword);
Also, is there a specific terminology about this kind of export orderHandler.js ? (like something called "an arrowed object" or "topped class level export")
I searched on Node.js documentation, without success.
With the help of AI, I managed a result, but the code became way less elegant (but still working).

you can change module.exports = ... to export default .... there's no special name for this, it's just a module that exports a function

@Mulan I was so perplexe about your reply... but yeah, it was that simple, thanks you!
On the other side, it was a bit more tricky with the import side, but managed a pretty cool solution in two lines :
import connectHandler from "../src/handlers/connectHandlers.js"
then
const {requestList} = connectHandler(io)

Nice work, that's exactly right. If the module also export other names, you can import * as H from "../handlers" then const {requestList} = H.default(io). Or you can combine both import connect, * as H from "../handlers" then const {requestList} = connect(io), and const foo = H.someFunc(bar).

Thanks to @Mulan and because I come back here every 4 months, here the complete code in ECMAScript :

index.js
import {createServer} from "http";
import {Server} from "socket.io";

import orderHandler from "../src/handlers/orderHandler.js"
import userHandler from "../src/handlers/userHandler.js"


const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer);

const { createOrder, readOrder } = orderHandler(io)
const { updatePassword } = userHandler(io)

const onConnection = (socket) => {
    socket.on("order:create", createOrder);
    socket.on("order:read", readOrder);

    socket.on("user:update-password", updatePassword);
}

io.on("connection", onConnection);

httpServer.listen(3000);
console.log("Server started on port 3000");


orderHandler.js
export default (io) => {
    const createOrder = function (payload) {
        const socket = this; // hence the 'function' above, as an arrow function will not work
        // ...
    };

    const readOrder = function (orderId, callback) {
        // ...
    };

    return {
        createOrder,
        readOrder
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
